# How could I render to a string a JSON representation of a JBuilder view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm using [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) as to return some JSON. I have a `index.json.jbuilder` that generates the data, and I need to render it to a string. However, I'm not sure how to do this, since: `@my_object.to_json` and `@my_object.as_json` don't seem to go through JBuilder.

How could I render the JBuilder view as a string?

Comment: Are you trying to return JSON from a controller as a JSON response or literally build a JSON string in isolation?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I am rendering a collection of users as a json string in the controller like so:

```
#controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
  @users = User.all
  @users_json = render_to_string( template: 'users.json.jbuilder', locals: { users: @users})
end

#views/users/users.json.jbuilder
json.array!(users) do |json, user|
  json.(user, :id, :name)
end
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, I tried implementing the above technique, but when I go to the page, I get a missing template error: "Missing template /work.json with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :jbuilder, :coffee]}." I'm a little new to rails, and not quite sure what's going on. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am guessing you may need to add "respond_to :json" in your controller.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with "respond_to :json" in my controller

Comment: @arron Not sure if this is the best way, but I finally got it working like this: "@work_json = render_to_string "work", :layout => false", and renaming my jbuilder file to "work.html.jbuilder". Your answer definitely put me on the right track though. +1 thanks!

Comment: the answer doesn't work for me. render_to_string changes the content type of the response to json (index should render html)

Comment: This doesn't work as written here -- same error as jordancooperman.

Comment: calling the index method is going to render a string and assign it to the @users_json instance variable, from there you do what you please. If you want to output something you need to add a respond to block or create a view for the requested content type.

Comment: maletor if you are having a problem rendering the template you may need to specify the format. render_to_string :template => "template", :formats => [:json] rails usually deduces the format from the template name "users.json.jbuilder" format should be set as json.

Comment: If you want the view to continue rendering HTML after producing the JSON (for example to include the JSON in the HTML page), you need to tell Rails to switch back to HTML format. You can add a line at the end of the action like this: `render :index, formats: [:html]`

Answer (score 9):

If the view `users.json.jbuilder` is at the default path relative to the controller and it cannot find the template, it may be due to a `format` discrepancy, as it may be trying to look for the `html` format file. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Have the client GET `/users/index.json`

   **or**
2. Specify the `formats` option when calling `render_to_string` (also applies to `render`):

---

```
#controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
  @users = User.all
  @users_json = render_to_string( formats: 'json' ) # Yes formats is plural
end
```

This has been verified in Rails 4.1.

Comment: I think this should be voted as solution since it works for the common case and is much easier than the chosen solution

Comment: Anyone on a rails 4.1 should be using THIS answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing this in the controller, a much simpler option is to try to the move the code into the view being rendered by the controller.

I described this here:
https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/blob/master/docs/jbuilder.md

basically you can call `render` in the view, and you're done. Like this:

```
<%= react_component('App', render(template: "/comments/index.json.jbuilder"),
    generator_function: true, prerender: true) %>
```

Here's the notes on what happens if you want to pass the data from the controller to the view:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all

    # NOTE: The below notes apply if you want to set the value of the props in the controller, as
    # compared to he view. However, it's more convenient to use Jbuilder from the view. See
    # app/views/pages/index.html.erb:20
    #
    #  <%= react_component('App', render(template: "/comments/index.json.jbuilder"),
    #     generator_function: true, prerender: true) %>
    #
    #
    # NOTE: this could be an alternate syntax if you wanted to pass comments as a variable to a partial
    # @comments_json_sting = render_to_string(partial: "/comments/comments.json.jbuilder",
    #                                         locals: { comments: Comment.all }, format: :json)
    # NOTE: @comments is used by the render_to_string call
    # @comments_json_string = render_to_string("/comments/index.json.jbuilder")
    # NOTE: It's CRITICAL to call respond_to after calling render_to_string, or else Rails will
    # not render the HTML version of the index page properly. (not a problem if you do this in the view)
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html
    # end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this, which leaves your controller a bit cleaner.

```
# controller
def new
  @data = Data.all
end


# view
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var mydata = <%= raw render :partial => 'path/to/partial', :locals => {data: @data} %>;
  </script>
<% end %>


# path/to/_partial.html.jbuilder
json.array!(@data) do |d|
  json.extract! field1, :field2, :field3, :field4
  json.url data_url(d, format: :json)
end


# layouts/application.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd prefer this approach, also, you can make it format agnostic by dropping format part from extensions, i.e. `_partial.jbuilder` can be  used from inside of both json and html views.

Comment: This approach is nice, except it doesn't work within `content_tag`'s data attributes. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, it looks like you can do:

```
json_string = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.partial! 'path/to/index', @my_object
end
```

Comment: I tried for about 20 minutes in a shell to do it, without much luck. If it's not too much to ask, could you maybe post a working example of this?

Comment: I pulled this code snippet from the Jbuilder examples in the docs: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

It looks like embedded templates may be broken under Ruby 1.8 and only work on Ruby 1.9 and above.

Comment: json.partial! 'path/to/index', my_object: @my_object
This is right syntax

Comment: json = JbuilderTemplate.new(view_context) do |json|
      json.partial! 'filename'
    end.attributes!

note that you need "_filename" because it calls partial renderer.

Answer (score 2):

From console:

```
view = ApplicationController.view_context_class.new("#{Rails.root}/app/views")
JbuilderTemplate.encode(view){|json| json.partial!('path/to/index', @my_object) }
```

via https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/84#issuecomment-38109709

Answer (score 1):

in controller you can do like this

```
def index
  json = JbuilderTemplate.new(view_context) do |json|
    json.partial! 'index'
  end.attributes!
  do_something(json)
  render json: json
end
```

note that you need "_index.json.jbuilder" because it calls partial renderer

Answer (score 0):

Following justingordon's tip.

If you are using a React component, you can do the following.

In your controller:

```
@users = User.all
```

In your view:

```
<%= react_component("YourComponentName",
                    props: render('your_template.json.jbuilder')) %>
```

This was tested on Rails 5.1.